# Is it safe to modify a field that is being used to update another field?

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

Now this is a valid statement that executes, and I have observed it performing the desired operation. My question: is it reliable to do this in a single statement in SQL Server? By reliable, I mean that `Foo` will be set to `Bar`'s original value before `Bar`'s value is changed to `null`.

```
update SomeTable
set Foo = Bar,
    Bar = null
```

Note that I am asking a question about the fundamental design of SQL Server. Hence I'm interested in answers that go beyond observation, and either cite Microsoft (or old sybase) documentation and/or convincingly demonstrates why SQL Server works a certain way at a low, fundamental level.

Comment: Interesting question, have you tried it?  Should be pretty easy to set up.

Comment: I wonder what would happen if you altered the update order?

Comment: I've observed that order doesn't matter. I am interested in something more fundamental than observation. I'm interested in if the reliability of this statement is either baked into the SQL standard or SQL Server.

Comment: `update @SomeTable set Foo = Bar, Bar = foo` That's even weirder, they  end up switched instead of the same. (Though really it is the same behavior)

Comment: @DanielE. your test supports the assumption that the data structure with the original values is different from the one with the outputted values. I'd like to hear someone explain how SQL Server works at a low enough level to turn that assumption into fact, and back up those low-level claims by referencing Microsoft documentation or by some other means.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this will behave as you wish it to in SQL Server. Foo will be set to Bar before Bar is set to NULL.

EDIT: Source - http://dba.fyicenter.com/faq/sql_server/Importance_of_Column_Order_in_SET_Clause.html

Comment: Thank you , but please back up your claim.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be on safe side I would split this UPDATE into TWO Separate Update statements and wrap two UPDATE statements inside ONE transaction.

I dont think the order in which you mention columns in SET clause decides what column is updated first. 
Therefore to keep matter simple, I would do as follows...

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

 update SomeTable
    set Foo = Bar

 update SomeTable
   set Bar = null

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: Thank you, although a fine technique to side-step the problem, it does not address the question.

Answer (score 1):

`SET` column order does not matter.  During an update, SQL Server is maintaining an old copy of the row and a new copy of the row.  All calculations are done using the old values only.

You can even do this to swap the values in two columns

```
update SomeTable
set Foo = Bar,
    Bar = Foo
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1c257/3)

Comment: This is the kind of answer I was expecting. Is there MSDN or any other documentation that states that an old copy of the record is used when calculating the new field values (i.e. the input variables are different from the output variables)?